# How do I OPEN a stored excel file in SQL Server 2008 via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have stored an excel file in my SQL Server 2008 DB (as a VARBINARY(MAX)) the following (so far, hard coded) way:

```
// C# - visual studio 2008
var update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Requests SET Attachment = @xls" +
        " WHERE RequestsID = 27", conn);
     update.Parameters.AddWithValue("xls", File.ReadAllBytes("C:/aFolder/hello.xlsx"));
     update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It works, but **I want to open it too**!
How do I do that?
Note, not read blob-data, but open the actual "hello.xlsx" file.

I have tried the following:
http://dotnetsoldier.blogspot.com/2007/07/how-to-retrieve-blob-object-in-winforms.html
I can see it works, as "Binary.Length" is exactly the size of my "hello.xlsx" when executing - but the file doesn´t open, and that´s my problem.

Please help me out!

EDIT:
HERE IS THE CODE THAT I CURRENTLY USE TO "OPEN" THE SPREADSHEET:

```
SqlConnection conn =
        new SqlConnection
           (global::MY_PROJECT.Properties.Settings.Default.DB_1ConnectionString);

     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("select Attachment from Requests where RequestsID = 27", conn);
     Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     SqlDataReader Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
     //
     string DocumentName = null;
     FileStream FStream = null;
     BinaryWriter BWriter = null;
     //
     //
     //
     byte[] Binary = null;
     const int ChunkSize = 100;
     int SizeToWrite = 0;
     MemoryStream MStream = null;
     //
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
        DocumentName = Reader["Attachment"].ToString();
        // Create a file to hold the output.
        FStream = new FileStream(@"c:\" + DocumentName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        BWriter = new BinaryWriter(FStream);
        Binary = (Reader["Attachment"]) as byte[];
        SizeToWrite = ChunkSize;
        MStream = new MemoryStream(Binary);
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < Binary.GetUpperBound(0) - 1; i = i + ChunkSize)
        {
           if (i + ChunkSize >= Binary.Length) SizeToWrite = Binary.Length - i;
           byte[] Chunk = new byte[SizeToWrite];
           MStream.Read(Chunk, 0, SizeToWrite);
           BWriter.Write(Chunk);
           BWriter.Flush();
        }
        BWriter.Close();
        FStream.Close();
     }
     FStream.Dispose();

     conn.Close();
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to open the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks like it probably writes the spreadsheet to disc but I can't see any code to open it. You would need to use something like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\" + DocumentName)
```

I think.

Comment: An excel sheet is opened, but it´s named "System.Byte[]", and contains only rubbish data... any tips? Also, of course, the DocumentName contains "System.Byte[]".

Comment: @Jack - Ah that's clearly a problem with either the way you are saving the file to the database or the way you are writing it to disc that is causing corruption then. My C# is pretty rusty at the moment hopefully someone else will spot the issue...